# Suppose $f \in L^{\infty}[0,1]$ is this true that $f(x)$ integrable on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f \in L^{\infty}[0,1]$ is this true that $f(x)$ integrable on $[0,1]$ ?

When we say $f \in L^p[E]$ it is already assumed that $f$ is a measurable (extended real valued ?) function and $E$ is a measurable set. And because $f$ is essentially bounded on $E$ we can split the integral as $$\int_Ef= \int_{E \setminus E_0} f + 
 \int_{E_0}f$$ Where $E_0= \{ x \in E : f(x) = \infty  \}$ and $mE_0 = 0$. Can we claim that $
 \int_{E_0}f = 0 $?

If Yes,This shows that $f$ is integrable on $E$.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the function in $L^{\infty}$ is assumed to be measurable. Bounded functions are the first ones you use when defining an integral on a finite interval. So, yes, they are integrable on a finite interval. All bets are off, though, when you work with a measure on an underlying set with infinite measure such as the Lebesgue measure on $[0,\infty)$ or on all of $\mathbb{R}$.